# Spring RequestMapping with root path (/{custom})

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Let's say my website name is: *foo.com*

When a user types *foo.com*, I want to show **index.html**.

When a user types *foo.com/something*, I want the server catches the request at the controller.

Here is what I did in the HomeController:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping(value={"/"}, method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getHome() {
        return "index.html";
    }
}
```

And, the CustomController should catch the request

```
@Controller
public class CustomController {
    @RequestMapping(value={"/{custom}"}, method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getCustom(@PathVariable String custom) {
        // Do something here..
    }
}
```

However, it throws an error: *Circular view path [index.html]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/index.html] again.* It's because the CustomController catches the GET request: *foo.com/index.html* after the HomeController returns the string: index.html.

I did some research like this:

```
public class WebMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/assets/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/assets"); // My asset
        registry.addResourceHandler("index.html").addResourceLocations("file:/index.html");
    } // It's not working

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("forward:/" + FileNames.INDEX);
    } // This also not working
}
```

And changing the annotation from @Controller to @RestController in the CustomController is not an option.

Also, I don't have JSP files in the project - they are plain *.html files.

[image: My project setup]

I am using Spring 1.3.3 release, so please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution works with **ui-router** (AngularJS library).  Also, you have to change *$resourceProvider* setting:

```
// In your app module config
$resourceProvider.defaults.stripTrailingSlashes = false;
```

Then, in the Spring server codes, you can do this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{custom:[^\\.]*}")
public String redirect(@PathVariable String custom) {
  // Do something here...
  return "forward:/";
}
```

Found the solution at this link: https://spring.io/blog/2015/05/13/modularizing-the-client-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-vii